# passing variable from vbscript to batch file

Tags: vbscript

i am using vbscript to call a batch file. my script looks like:

```
dim shell  
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")  
shell.run "a.bat"  
set shell=nothing
```

my batch file is simple and looks like:

```
D:  
cd D:\d  
winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a
```

i want to pass a variable from a script to the batch file. lets say the destination folder.
how do i do that?
any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you can just pass variables to the batch file. 
You can call it like:

```
shell.run "a.bat var1 var2"
```

And in your batch file, you can refer to them as:

```
%1 for "var1"
%2 for "var2"
```

And you can do this from %1 to %9.