# Pass vbs variable to batch file

Tags: vbscript, dos

I am trying to pass a vbs variable as an argument into my batch file:

vbs code:

```
Set WShShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim nextday
nextday= DateAdd("d",1,dtmStart)
strRun = "Batch1.bat" & nextday
WshShell.Run(strRun)
```

batch code:

```
"C:\AscendQrx\bselstmt.exe" NOCONFIRM DATABASE=ddd var=ccc date=nextday
```

Getting the error bad syntax.

Comment: Start with putting a space between the name of the .bat and the date: `strRun = "Batch1.bat " & nextday`. Then in the .bat pick up the (one and only) command line parameter: `... date=%1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing variable from vbscript to batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536695/passing-variable-from-vbscript-to-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

why not run the command from the vbscript instead of calling a batch file?  I used to do the same thing before I became more familiar how to use .Run

Try this and let me know

```
Set WShShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim nextday
nextday= DateAdd("d",1,dtmStart)
strRun = "C:\AscendQrx\bselstmt.exe NOCONFIRM DATABASE=ddd var=ccc date=" & nextday
WshShell.Run(strRun)
```